# jQuery scrolling issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

Does anyone know why the site loads in this portion of the page? I am gussing it is jQuery related. It is live here : http://littleboxcreative.com/lilboxer/

The site loads in the portfolio section instead of the home section where i would like it to load.

Answer (score 0):

he problem is this from style.css

```
#main {
    width: 9000px;
    height: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-image:url('http://littleboxcreative.com/img/plum.png');
}
```

You will need to have it within a container set to overflow:hidden ie

```
#maincontainer {
width:980px;
overflow:hidden
}
```

This hides everything except the first 980px, then your slider slides in the next when the user scrolls.

Once you have fixed that then you will need to add some jQuery to allow the user to move between your #mainwrap panels, or set it to autoplay as a slider.

Comment: You need to add <div id="maincontainer"> above <div id="main"> and close it after the closing </div> of #main